# Seating robots in a row

Tags: combinatorics

We need to seat robots (which we cannot tell apart) in a row with 15 seats in the following manner:

1. There are no 2 robots sitting near each other.
2. Around every empty seat there must be at least one robot sitting.

There is no restriction on the amount of robots.
(Can be anything that fits)

We need to find the amount of possible arrengements of the robots.

*Notice that we cannot have two empty seats at the corners.

*I have computed it using a simple program, and the answer is 65.

I now need to find a proper combinatorical solution/proof.

Example for all the possibilities for 5 seats:

01001
01010
10010
10101

Possible arrengements: 4

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your task? To what question is $65$ the answer? I guess the number of possibilites to position robots. But how many are there? Or is the number arbitrary?

Comment: How many robots are there?

Comment: That is implied by the rules.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I suppose because then the empty seat at the end won't satisfy 2

Comment: Can you post some example patterns? From the rules it looks like there is only one pattern possible, seating them in alternate positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n,b_n,c_n$ be the number of such arrangements ending in a seat occupied by a robot, an empty seat that may be followed by another empty seat, an empty seat that may not be followed by an empty seat.
We are looking for $a_{15}+b_{15}$.
We have initial values $$a_1=1, b_1=0, c_1=1$$ and recursions
$$ a_{n+1}=b_n+c_n,\quad b_{n+1}=a_n,\quad c_{n+1}=b_n$$
which simlpifies to $a_{n+1}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $f_i(n)$ is the number of ways of seating on $n$ seats with $i$ empty seats at the end then 
$$\begin{align*}f_0(n) &= f_1(n-1)+f_2(n-1)\\
f_1(n) &= f_0(n-1)\\
f_2(n) &= f_0(n-2)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: *There may not be more than 2 empty seats in a row.

Comment: @NightRa and hence I don't have any $f_i$ for $i>2$.